# groupby first as a dictionary in pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have data frame as shown below.

```
session      slot_num     appt_time
s1           1            2020-01-06 09:00:00
s1           2            2020-01-06 09:20:00
s1           3            2020-01-06 09:40:00
s1           3            2020-01-06 09:40:00
s1           4            2020-01-06 10:00:00
s1           4            2020-01-06 10:00:00
s2           1            2020-01-06 08:20:00
s2           2            2020-01-06 08:40:00
s2           2            2020-01-06 08:40:00
s2           3            2020-01-06 09:00:00
s2           4            2020-01-06 09:20:00
s2           5            2020-01-06 09:40:00
s2           5            2020-01-06 09:40:00
s2           6            2020-01-06 10:00:00
s3           1            2020-01-09 13:00:00
s3           1            2020-01-09 13:00:00
s3           2            2020-01-09 13:20:00
s3           3            2020-01-09 13:40:00
```

from the above I want to create a dictionary with key as session and value as a starting time of each appt_time.

Expected Output:

```
d = {'S1':'2020-01-06 09:00:00',
     'S2':'2020-01-06 08:20:00',
     'S3':'2020-01-09 13:00:00'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with convert `sesion` to index, select column for `Series` and last use [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = df.drop_duplicates('session').set_index('session')['appt_time'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'s1': '2020-01-06 09:00:00', 's2': '2020-01-06 08:20:00', 's3': '2020-01-09 13:00:00'}
```